# Deserialize and get xml having 2 attributes with different ID

Tags: c#, .net, xml-deserialization

I want to Deserialize and get values of 2 attributes with different ID.

```XML
<Attributes><AddressAttribute ID="18"><AddressAttributeValue><Value>Sala 305</Value></AddressAttributeValue></AddressAttribute><AddressAttribute ID="17"><AddressAttributeValue><Value>3434</Value></AddressAttributeValue></AddressAttribute></Attributes>
```

I treid this C# code but it only returns the 1st attribute.
please help

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "AddressAttributeValue")]

public class AddressAttributeValue
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value")]

    public string Value { get; set; }

}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "AddressAttribute")]

public class AddressAttribute
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AddressAttributeValue")]

    public AddressAttributeValue AddressAttributeValue { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ID")]

    public string ID { get; set; }

}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Attributes")]

public class Attributes

{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AddressAttribute")]

    public AddressAttribute AddressAttribute { get; set; }

}

 var xmlData= customer.BillingAddress.CustomAttributes;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Attributes));
        Attributes data;
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlData))
        {
            data = (Attributes)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
```

Should I change classes of Deserialize logic???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes using Linq instead of xml serialization can be simpler

```
var list = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring).Descendants("AddressAttribute")
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Id = (int)x.Attribute("ID"),
            Value = (string)x.Element("AddressAttributeValue").Element("Value")
        })
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Attributes")]
public class Attributes
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AddressAttribute")]

    public AddressAttribute AddressAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

Change it to:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Attributes")]
public class Attributes
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AddressAttribute")]

    public AddressAttribute[] AddressAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

As you need to have collection of `AddressAttribute` you need to declare as an array.